# Spoon doesn´t launch

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I've already set all the environment variables but my Spoon.bat still doesn´t launch, even though it seems to warn no errors.

When I execute the Spoon.bat the window closes in less than 1 second and shows only these 3 lines.

```
DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: this happens when java path is not properly defined.

Answer (score 0):

I would try running from a command prompt and run SpoonDebug.bat instead.  The window should remain open and any additional information should be displayed.